# Tensorflow Image Classification Tutorial, crash on the second epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I'm trying to replicate the TensorFlow Image Classification Tutorial found here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

However, for some reason, the program crashes with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409), after the first epoch.

Here's the code that I have copied:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)

roses = list(data_dir.glob('roses/*'))
tulips = list(data_dir.glob('tulips/*'))

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,#originally 0.2
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


class_names = train_ds.class_names

#Configure the DataSet for performance
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE


#.cache = keeps the img in memory after they have been loaded off disk during the first epoch
#.prefetch = overlaps data preprocessing and model execution while training
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

#standardizing the RGB values to be within [0,1] range

normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))

num_classes = 5

model = Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'), #Relu is Mutually exlusive, the initial classification
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'), #
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

and here's the output:

```
2021-03-10 11:33:28.285891: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
3670
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.
2021-03-10 11:33:40.172866: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-10 11:33:40.182801: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.600845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.8605GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2021-03-10 11:33:40.602057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.680462: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.680774: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.725064: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.762494: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.826237: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.879988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:40.886178: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.052224: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-10 11:33:41.065505: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-10 11:33:41.067812: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.8605GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2021-03-10 11:33:41.068679: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.069536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.069884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.070227: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.072721: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.072988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.073254: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.073754: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-03-10 11:33:41.074267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-03-10 11:33:43.232733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-10 11:33:43.233087: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-03-10 11:33:43.233294: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-03-10 11:33:43.234651: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1366 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2021-03-10 11:33:43.238580: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 734 files for validation.
2021-03-10 11:33:43.923781: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-03-10 11:33:54.037806: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 53 of 1000
2021-03-10 11:34:03.968256: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 87 of 1000
2021-03-10 11:34:04.136991: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:230] Shuffle buffer filled.
0.0 1.0
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
rescaling_1 (Rescaling)      (None, 180, 180, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 180, 180, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 90, 90, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 90, 90, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 45, 45, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 45, 45, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 22, 22, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 30976)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               3965056   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 645       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,989,285
Trainable params: 3,989,285
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
2021-03-10 11:34:08.244592: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:34:09.792816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-10 11:34:09.825987: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

What am I doing wrong & what's the cause of this problem?

**My specs:**
Intel (R) Core (TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.70GHz

8GB RAM

64. bit operating system, x64-based processor

NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX with GeForce Game Ready Driver (v. 461.72)

**Python version:** 3.8.5

**TensorFlow:** tensorflow._api.v2.version

**CUDA:** 11.0

Comment: Are you running out of memory? 8BG doesn't seem like a lot to me. I struggle running some tensorflow jobs on my 16GB laptop.

Comment: as a matter of fact I did (although not with this example).  10/10 would recommend Google Collab for training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted cudnn64_8.dll from the CUDA folder, and added CUDNN main folder to the path (instead of the pin as before.